# R clean Start Code RStudio crash (sometimes)

Tags: r, function, lapply, detach

I have created this cleanStart function for R. It is made so the programmers have to create code including all library and variable loading. (decreasing the chance of incomplete code)

I tested this manny times but sometimes RStudio will crash on this code. 
Suggestions on improvement or perhaps i'm overlooking / forgetting things.

```
cleanStart <- function(){
 keep <- c(
        ".GlobalEnv",
        ".rs.describeObject",
        "Autoloads",
        "tools:rstudio",
        "package:stats",
        "package:graphics",
        "package:grDevices",
        "package:utils",
        "package:datasets",
        "package:methods",
        "package:base"
        )
 lapply(which(!search() %in% keep),function(i){detach(search()[i],character.only = TRUE, unload=TRUE)})
 rm(list = ls()); cat("\014") 
}; suppressWarnings(cleanStart())
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What about base R, does it crash, too?

Comment: No problems as far as i can see: R CMD BATCH cleanStart.R But i will run this multiple times to see if problems will occur after loading all kind of packages (some require others)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with completely different code in RStudio but not base R. The problem was that I had a large R data object saved in my project directory with an extension of .R instead of .Rda. RStudio was trying to read this large object in at load, and so when I tried to run something, most of my memory was being used and RStudio would crash. You might want to check if you have any other large .R files in your project directory.

Comment: Hi Sharon, Thanks for the replay. There are no large objects in R. After writing the code i ran it multiple times in a row to see if it is stable and save to use. So each next itteration R is empty or only contains some packages is load in de process. It just sometimes does not work. I work under Linux. Yesterday i tried running the same function multiple times under windows. Up till now no problem. I will do a trial under Unix as well. I think that the problem has to do with nested libraries. (Package using another packages) Would be nice to have clean Start code that works flawlessly. Ideas?